# How to declare variable In T-SQL and use it in update statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

New to SQL scripting, trying to update part of a string in SQL script using define variable as below but can't get it to work. The column can be like `\\OM-WD08-1\TestDoc\report\rep.pdf` there are lot of table with different column heading to update. I want to declare the variable and substitute where applicable. thanks in advance

```
USE MyServer

-- Declare the variable to be used.
DECLARE @OldPath varchar(30), @NewPath varchar(30)

-- Initialize the variable
SET @OldPath ='\\OM-WD08-1\';
SET @NewPath ='\\AA-PC\';

UPDATE AnatomyConfigs
SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @OldPath, @NewPath) 
WHERE Path IS NOT NULL
  AND Path LIKE @OldPath
GO
```

Comment: `Path LIKE @OldPath` will never be true if `Path` is null, so your first check is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` only performs a literal match of text unless you include some form of wildcards (`%` or `_`). I would do this:

```sql
USE MyServer

-- Declare the variable to be used.

DECLARE @OldPath varchar(30), @NewPath varchar(30)

-- Initialize the variable
SET @OldPath ='\\OM-WD08-1\';
SET @NewPath ='\\AA-PC\';

UPDATE AnatomyConfigs
    SET Path = @NewPath + SUBSTRING(Path,LEN(@OldPath)+1,8000)
WHERE Path LIKE @OldPath + '%'
GO
```

I prefer to use `SUBSTRING` over `REPLACE` because it more cleanly reflects "I just want to replace an instance that occurs at the start of the string". Now, given that no path should contain `\\`s in the middle, this is not really required in this specific case, but I'm going for a more general answer.

Comment: Thanks Damien, your solution worked. save me a lot of searching time. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @varibale_name varhcar(50)
To set Value:
set @variable_name='dgnughg'

update Table_Name set column_name=@variable_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I prefer Damien answer